# Image in not showing in image view while in postman it's working well

Tags: java, android, spring

I am really confused to show a image in `ImageView`. Actually when i am hitting my `URL` i am getting a file and another thing when i am hitting my URL in postman it's working well. And when i am trying to use `Glide` and other thing like `Picasso` i am not getting images from server.

Pleas suggest me what i can do for it.

My server code in java is here you can check it also.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "downloadBlog", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> downloadBlogImage(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long id) {

    StayHealthyBlog dbFile = checkUserService.findBlogById(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(dbFile.getImageType()))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"xyz" + "\"")
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(dbFile.getImageData()));
}
```

Now how i can get my image..

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: the code that you have shared has nothing related to setting the downloaded image to imageview. Have you done that ?

Comment: @Vivek Mishra this code is Rest  API code now i am using Picasso.load(url).into image view but problem is when hitting my url getting download a file not showing image on browser.

Comment: when you are downloading image then why are you passing url in picasso ? Pass the uri of the download file

Comment: it's coming in file format not in jpeg or png

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this line:**

> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = "downloadBlog", method = RequestMethod.GET)
> ```

**With:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "downloadBlog", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
```

**Update**

**Ensure URL** start with `http://` for `Glide` or `Picasso` to recognise link protocol.

```
    Picasso.get().load("http://" + url).into(imageView); // If server return url without `http{s}://`
```